# how to pass radiobutton value using ajax from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var radioVal = $("input[name='price']:checked").val();
    });
}
```

I need to pass `radioVal` value to another jsp

Comment: What is your use case? Are you rendering a partial jsp from inside another jsp, or do you need to submit a form and have the value of the radio button in the jsp after the form is processed? Or something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: I am not going to submit the form in first jsp and the 2 jsps are in different path.In second jsp i want to pass the radio button value as hidden field to the controller.<input type="hidden" id="condition" name="condition" class="form-control" value="${cond}">.This is the code in second jsp.i want to pass radiobutton value to ${cond}

Answer (score 0):

Please Take the help of Following Example.

page1.jsp

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var radioVal;
     $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
             radioVal = $("[name=radio]:checked").val();
             alert(radioVal);
             $.post("page2.jsp", {"processId": radioVal })
        });

});

</script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="first"/> 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="second"/> 2 <br/>
```

page2.jsp

```
<%
System.out.println(request.getParameter("processId"));
%>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,this seems to be not working as my second jsp is not in same path.

Comment: you can provide path of that jsp in ajax.